# java graphics create an N by N board

Tags: java, graphics

I have this question I haven't solved left in my assignment, "cmps200: introduction to java programming". This is what I wrote but it gives a blank panel:

```
import java.awt.*;
public class Board {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         int N= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int x=0;
        int y=0;
        int m=(int)(300/5);
        DrawingPanel panel= new DrawingPanel(300, 300);
        Graphics g= panel.getGraphics();
        for (int i=1; i<=N; i++){
            for (int j=1; j<=N; j++){
                square();
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                circle();
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                circle();
                y+=m;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void square(){
        int N;
        int m= (int)(300/5);
        int x=0; int y=0;
        DrawingPanel panel= new DrawingPanel(300, 300);
        Graphics g= panel.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x, y, N/300, N/300);
    }
    public static void circle(){
        int x; int y; int m;
        Graphics g= panel.getGraphics();
        g.fillOval(x+y+(3/2)*m);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's a DrawingPanel? I'm assuming that is your class?

Comment: `int N;` not initialized in your `square()` method. same for `int x; int y; int m;` in your `circle method`

Comment: Don't use `getGraphics`, this not not how custom painting should be done and can return `null` and won't be updated on the next paint cycle. See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Properly pass parameters:

```
public class Board {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ...
        for (int i=1; i<=N; i++){
            for (int j=1; j<=N; j++){
                square(N);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                circle(x, y);
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                circle(x, y);
                y+=m;
            }
        }
    }
    public static void square(int N){
        //deleted first line
        int m= (int)(300/5);
        int x=0; int y=0;
        DrawingPanel panel= new DrawingPanel(300, 300);
        Graphics g= panel.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(x, y, N/300, N/300);
    }
    public static void circle(int x, int y){
        //deleted first line
        Graphics g= panel.getGraphics();
        g.fillOval(x+y+(3/2)*m);
    }
}
```

Comment: it still gives an empty panel